# Filtering data in DataTable/DataGridView by change in selected item of ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

**Current position:**

On form load, I currently have a combo box being populated with data from a SQL table. I also have a DataGridView populating from another SQL table. This code is as per below and is all working fine.

```
public void frmDataProcess_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Populate combo box
    custSQL cmbSQL = new custSQL();
    string strSQL = "SELECT Code, Description, Code FROM dbo.ProductGroup ORDER BY Code ASC";
    cmbSQL.sqlDataSetToComboBox(strSQL, "DevSageConnection", cmbProductGroupOrders, "ProductGroupNameDesc", "ProductGroupNameDesc");

    // Populate data grid view.
    custSQL sql = new custSQL();
    string strConnectionName = "DevSageConnection";
    string strConnectionString = sql.GetConnectionStringByName(strConnectionName);
    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            comm.Connection = conn;
            string query = "SELECT Code, Name FROM dbo.StockItem ORDER BY Code ASC";
            comm.CommandText = query;
            SqlDataAdapter dar = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dar.Fill(dt);
            dgvStockList.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

I am looking to initially load the data in to the DataGridView but then filter down the DataGridView with the data that is selected within the ComboBox when the user changes the selection within said ComboBox. I don't really want the whole of the data within DataGridView to "refresh" if you will because I will be allowing a column for user input and therefore can't lose this between transitions of the combo box.

So far, I have attempted to use the SelectedIndexChanged event on the ComboBox to drive a filter on the DataGridView but I was unsuccessful in passing any data in to this event and as such, the data table was inaccessible from within.

I have looked at other solutions which do not touch on passing the data table in to the event handler and as such they have been of little help.

What is the best way to approach a filter on the data whilst retaining the data that is already pulled in?

Comment: what about storing the data in a collection when you load it from the sql, I mainly use lists, and then clearing and repopulating the datagridview by parsing through the list with the filter condition(s)

Comment: @ZedLepplin thanks for the response, however, clearing re-populating the DataGridview would lose any user input to the DataGridView, something I am looking to retain.For instance, a user could input data in to the permitted column in the DataGridView and then choose a new option from the ComboBox, then add some more data. So its important to retain the existing data in there.

Comment: What about adding this data into the collection by picking up the events as the user inputs new data?

Comment: Ok, just to make sure that I am clear on what you are suggesting: Store the data in a collection at the time of the data loading (from SQL server) as well as populating this data in to the DataGridView to display to the user, then create an event handler for when a user inputs the further data and append this to the collection? Without ever using collections before, let alone in this manner, would you happen to have any code examples that may help? Thanks.

Comment: yes, I am doing this already. I am working with a lot of datagridview's linked to an sqllite db. My lists are populated on power up from the sql db, then I use the lists to populate my dgv's. In my application I use a save button that causes the datagirdview's data to be saved directly back in the database then I reload my lists from the database, but I could just as easily update the lists. Also in some places I do not have a save button, I have an event handler that detects that datagridview data has changed and that allows me to save the new data in the db, etc.

Comment: @ZedLepplin - This sounds like a viable solution, I will give this a go. Do you have any issues with accessing the List inside of the event handler for the data changing in the data grid view? This is something as per the question that I have been struggling to figure out. It always seems out of scope.

Comment: I am at the end of this project and I have not had any issue with accessing my lists from events.

Comment: If you haven’t already done so and since it appears from the posted code that you are working with a `DataTable`… to filter it… I suggest you take a look at the [`DataView` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1):

In exact repsond to your requirement, I would suggest is to fill a `DataTable` (as you did) to fill in the `StockItem` table. Then you will create a 2nd `DataTable` and use `.Select()` function with a filter rows you need.

```
dt2 = dt1.Select("MyKey=" + this.ComboBox1.SelectedValue + " ").CopyToDataTable();
```

and set your DataGridView datasource to the `dt2`, not the `dt1`. Then use a `CellEndEdit()` event to propagate the new user-edited value into `dt1`. I assume you will be saving whole `dt1` later (that seems to be one of your points).

However, I sense a bit bad design here. I think you shouldn't end up in this situation in the first place.

Comment: Thanks mate, your not wrong about the bad design, I am just at a bit of a loss on how to approach it otherwise. @Oak_3260548

Comment: I appended forgotten `.CopyToDataTable();` to my answer, just for clarity. As for your comment, it is difficult to suggest without knowing more detials. Fist it's important to understand, why you don't want to save the user edited column to the database at each `ComboBox.ValueChanged()` event? That would allow you to load next `DataGridView` set of rows from database, which is way more easy to handle and it's more reliable.

Comment: Thanks buddy, that is precisely what I got to in the end, just needed a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Great, glad it helped. Please mark the question as answered.